# Transcoding digital camera generated MOVs to AVI to reduce file size without compromising the quality further

Tags: video-encoding

My older digital camera used to make low quality 100MB+ (for 5 - 6 mins of video) **MOV files** for videos I took

I have **around 70GB of these videos** and I would like to bring them into a managable size **without compromising the quality further**.

Would transcoding it to AVI (perhaps XVID + MP3) work?

Which batch transcoding tool might help me do this with minimum manual intervention?

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off just to leave it as MOV.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov out.mov
```

**FFmpeg will assume**

H.264 video codec

High profile

AAC audio codec

128 kbit/s audio bitrate